# $A$ self adjoint matrix. Prove there is a real $c$ such that $cI+A$ is positive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

This was partially asked before (1. [There exists a real number $c$ such that $A+cI$ is positive when $A$ is symmetric](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74351), 2. [Proving $aI+A$ is Positive Definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1719136)) but I'd like revision of this proof using forms.

> Let $A$ be a self-adjoint $n \times n$  matrix. Prove that there is a real number $c$ such that the matrix $cI+A$ is positive

This is my attempt: 
Let be $f$ the form with matrix $A$ in the canonical basis. Since $A$ is self adjoint there exists a unitary matrix $Q$ such that
$$Q^*AQ = D$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. But this is just the matrix of the form $f$ in the basis composed of the column vectors of $Q$. Moreover, since $A$ is self adjoint it follows that every entry of the diagonal matrix D is real. 
So, consider the matrix $A+cI$ wich is also self adjoint and the consider the form $f'$ associated to this matrix. Again, there exists $P$ unitary such that $P^*(A+cI)P = D'$ is diagonal. But
$$P^*(A+cI)P = P^*AP + cP^*P = P^*AP + cI = D'$$
Choose $c$ so the entries of $D'$ are positive (for example, $c = 2\max \left\{
 |(P^*AP)_{ii}|: i \in \left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}\right\}$) and then obviously 
$$ X^*D'X > 0 \quad\forall X \in V$$
so the form $f'$ is positive and then $A+cI$ is positive (using the fact that if a form $f$ is positive then its matrix in **every** ordered basis is a positive matrix)
Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Answer (score 3):

Looks good! I do have one stylistic note: you use $D$ to represent two different diagonal matrices, which is a little confusing. Instead, you can assert that $Q^* A Q$ is diagonal, without naming it $D$ as well.

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback. I just edited the question for avoiding that confussion.

Comment: Oh, and one more comment, it's probably worth mentioning explicitly that $D$ has real entries, so that the maximum along the diagonal makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I edited the proof.